# Can we query from the mysql dump file (.sql) directly from C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have dumped mysql database and I get a file that has extension of Backup.**sql**. I want to ask that is their any way I can directly query(like Select * from products) from .sql file using C# programming language.

Comment: The question is why do you want to do this. jsut restore the database somewhere else, and the world is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not. You need a SQL server OR you could use some sort of non-client-server database engine, such as [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html). You would still have to import your data.

Comment: Thanks I will try that